# Writing a recursive method that analyses data from XML

Tags: c#, recursion

I need C# logic that analyse some conditions from an XML file. The logic should be able evaluate the conditions and just tell me whether the final result is true or false:

Example : 1 :
a rule (A AND B AND C) is represented like this in the XML file:

```
   <Evaluate>       
        <!-- (A AND B AND C)-->
        <AND>                               
            <Condition Name="A" Operator="!=" Value="0"/>
            <Condition Name="B" Operator="!=" Value="0"/>
            <Condition Name="C" Operator="==" Value="17"/>
        </AND>                
   </Evaluate>
```

I know this is simple thing to do, But below are some complex rules that needs evaluation from C# code:
Example : 2:

```
<Evaluate>
    <!-- (A AND B) OR C -->
    <OR>
        <Condition Name="C" Operator="==" Value="17"/>
        <AND>
            <Condition Name="A" Operator="!=" Value="0"/>
            <Condition Name="B" Operator="!=" Value="0"/>
        </AND>            
    </OR>                
</Evaluate>
```

Example: 3 :

```
<Evaluate>
    <!-- (A)  OR ((B AND C) OR D)-->
    <OR>
        <Condition Name="A" Operator="!=" Value="0"/>
        <OR>
            <Condition Name="D" Operator="!=" Value="0"/>
            <AND>
                <Condition Name="B" Operator="!=" Value="0"/>
                <Condition Name="C" Operator="!=" Value="0"/>                    
            </AND>
        </OR>
    </OR>               
</Evaluate>
```

Example: 4 :

```
<Evaluate>
    <!-- (A AND B)  OR ((C AND D) OR E)-->
    <OR>
        <AND>
            <Condition Name="A" Operator="!=" Value="0"/>
            <Condition Name="B" Operator="!=" Value="0"/>
        </AND>            
        <OR>
            <Condition Name="E" Operator="!=" Value="0"/>
            <AND>
                <Condition Name="C" Operator="!=" Value="0"/>
                <Condition Name="D" Operator="!=" Value="0"/>                    
            </AND>
        </OR>
    </OR>
</Evaluate>
```

To explain you about the the  Xml node:

```
<Condition Name="D" Operator="!=" Value="0"/>
```

means that the (D != 0) or not.

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: Interesting, I won't use recursion for this as it might run out of memory if the XML file is too big. You might need to go for writing your own parser ;)

Comment: @GETah: Any file which was big enough to cause problems would have to represent *phenomenally* complicated logic.

Comment: You've told us what you're trying to achieve, but nothing about which part you're finding difficult. How far have you got?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a sample for you

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("test.xml");
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        dict["A"] = 1;
        dict["B"] = 0;
        dict["C"] = 17;
        var result = Evaluate(doc.FirstChild,dict);
    }

    static bool Evaluate(XmlNode node, IDictionary<string, int> dict)
    {
        switch (node.Name)
        {
            case "Evaluate":
                return Evaluate(node.FirstChild.NextSibling, dict); // Ignore first comment
            case "Condition":
                return Condition(node, dict);
            case "AND":
                return And(node, dict);
            case "OR":
                return Or(node, dict);
            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }

    private static bool Or(XmlNode root, IDictionary<string, int> dict)
    {
        var result = false; // Starting with false, because It will be true when at least condition is true
        foreach (XmlNode node in root.ChildNodes)
        {
            result |= Evaluate(node, dict);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static bool And(XmlNode root, IDictionary<string, int> dict)
    {
        var result = true;
        foreach (XmlNode node in root.ChildNodes)
        {
            result &= Evaluate(node, dict);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static bool Condition(XmlNode node, IDictionary<string, int> dict)
    {
        var name = node.Attributes["Name"].Value;
        var value = node.Attributes["Value"].Value;
        var opt = node.Attributes["Operator"].Value;

        switch (opt)
        {
            case "==":
                return dict[name] == int.Parse(value);
            case "!=":
                return dict[name] != int.Parse(value);
            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works perfectly! But one question why result is set to true in both And and Or methods? I was thinking that, in case of And, the result should initialized be true and in case of Or the result should be initialized to false. So that, when two parameters are Ored and Anded, based on the result of the first parameter, it shall be possible to decide the result of And and Or? what do you think? I know you are just giving me a sample code. but i want some clarifications on the optimization as well.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this will get you started.

```
// warning, not tested
bool Evaluate(XmlNode node)
{
  // what kind of node is this? call one of the other functions
}

bool Condition(XmlNode node)
{
  // this is a condition node, evaluate it
}

bool And(XmlNode node)
{
  bool val = true;
  foreach (XmlNode child in node.ChildNodes)
  {
     val = val && Evaluate(child);
  }
  return val;
}

bool Or(XmlNode node)
{
  bool val = false;
  foreach (XmlNode child in node.ChildNodes)
  {
     val = val || Evaluate(child);
  }
  return val;
}
```